# Ajax/Javascript User Status update

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

What I need to do is prepend the users latest status update with not only the newmsg and the users id but I need to also add my comment toggle link, my divider-postid div my users picture and name, my delete button, and my like and dislike button. So what I'd have is something like what Twitter and facebook do. ->Send the form data into ajax and print everything out into the feed. My profile.php has everything I use that needs to be included.

So is there a way I can call these blocks of html and display them in the prepended div after the Ajax success? Its really hard to explain as I don't know what I'm doing, but hopefully you get the idea. I'm just not up on all this.

PROFILE.PHP

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = $("#toid").val();
    var newmsg = $("#newmsg").val();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "insert.php",
    data: "toid=" + content + "&newmsg=" + newmsg, 
    success: function(){
    $("#myThing").prepend("<div class='userinfo'>"+newmsg+" </div>");
    }
    });
    });
    });
    </script>
    <div class="userinfo"><div id="divider">
    <div class="form">
    <form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
    <input type="hidden"  name="toid" id="toid" value="<?php echo $user1_id; ?>">
    <input class="input" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="button_block">
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed">
    </div>
    </form>
    </div></div></div></body>
    <p id="myThing"></p>



  COMMENT LINK

echo "<div class='stream_option'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\"> Write a comment...</a></div>";
}else{
echo "<div class='stream_option'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\"> Show Comments (".$num2.")</a></div>";
```

LIKE LINK

```
cho "<div class='stream_option'><a id='likecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.id);\">";
```

DISLIKE LINK

```
echo "<div class='stream_option'><a id='dislikecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.id);\">";
```

DELETE LINK

```
<? if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$_SESSION['id']){
echo "<div style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:-70px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');\">X</div>";}
```

Comment: Your code is a little unintelligible, you should refine your question. Seems to me your problem is directly envolved to Javascript/HTML, then you sould show us only your HTML output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess here:

```
success: function(){
  $("#myThing").prepend("<div class='userinfo'>"+newmsg+" </div>");
}
```

Is where you're inserting the HTML? If that's the case, and if insert.php returns HTML, try this:

```
success: function(r){
  $("#myThing").prepend("<div class='userinfo'>"+newmsg+r.responseText+" </div>");
}
```

---

To get the ID:
I guess the insertion is done with mysql, so after the new message is inserted you'd do:

```
$new_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

and then output the HTML:

```
echo "<div class='stream_option'><a id='likecontext_".$new_id."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus(".$new_id.",this.id);\">";

echo "<div class='stream_option'><a id='dislikecontext_".$new_id."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus(".$new_id.",this.id);\">";

if ($new_id == $_SESSION['id'])
  echo "<div style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:-70px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('".$new_id."');\">X</div>";
```

Comment: Yes it is. But all my html links are in my home.php. See this is what is confusing me.

Comment: I'm confused. The responseText would be the items in the insert.php page right? If that is the case how will my above links work when all my php id's are calling the code in the php page likecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."..I don't fully understand.

Comment: So you're inserting to "insert.php" and you want to take links from "profile.php"? If you want to take HTML along with the new message when you call insert.php via Ajax, I guess the most practical thing to do is to make insert.php output the HTML you want.

Comment: So if I add the below link into my insert.php when it echo's out into the profile will it still get the streamiteam_data['id'] from home.php? Or do I have to add all the php into the insert.php page instead of the home.php..

echo "<div class='stream_option'><a id='dislikecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.id);\">";

Comment: That'll possibly work if $streamitem_data['streamitem_id'] is the ID of the new item inserted. In that case you could replace that var with the new ID which is probably possible to be captured after the insertion in insert.php. I don't see the code nor I know how it works so, you know, I'm just guessing here.

Comment: It is the ID of the newly inserted item. Would you mock up a quick example of how I'd go about the insert.php page please?

Comment: Thank you for that. I will have a go and let you know how it turns out.